# CentOS 7 machine lost connectivity after DDoS attack

Tags: networking, centos, centos7, internet, ddos

We were testing the DDoS protection of a CentOS 7 machine but after it ended, the connection on the machine is just gone. The configuration of the connection is exactly identical to before the DDoS attack, but both inbound as well as outbound traffic does not reach the server.

```
$ ping ip
PING ip (ip): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
^C
--- ip ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

An `ifconfig` returns what it should. Also handy to know, I can't ping the gateway either. And yes, DNS servers are set and I can't ping any IP's from the server itself either.

I realize this isn't a lot of information, so if you need more I'll gladly add it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't believe this - the IP was actually null routed! If you have the same problem as me, make sure to check this in your provider's control panel...

Comment: When you're attacking your own ip, albeit for testing purposes, you are also attacking the network infrastructure of your host.

Comment: @RPDiep not necessarily